# how to make an element span the full height of parent element with overflow: auto

Tags: css

Please see the following url for my example.

http://wiredbeast.com/bordermenu/test.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;background:green;overflow-y: auto;">
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <p>overflowing content</p>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:227px;bottom:0;background:red;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, when I shrink my window so that it activates the overflow on the green container, the red sidebar doesn't stretch all the way down. How can I have the sidebar span the whole height of its parent even with overflow?

Answer (score 0):

First, using an external stylesheet, or internal will help make this much neater and easier to work with. You also don't need to set an overflow, as most browsers will adjust automatically.

I would also set the width of the red `div` to `20%` so that will shrink with the window as well.

And you could just change it to position fixed and set the height to 100%

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `bottom:0;` for the outer div. That is causing the problem.

By setting this, it sets the height of the div to the bottom of the screen. So every time you expand the window, the red div just dies out right where you left it.

- Remove `bottom:0;` from the outer div style.

And it is always better to give a height.

- add `height:100%` to red div

Hope this helps.